# Semigroup of matrices and expander Cayley graphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, semigroups, spectral-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

I am interested in proving or disproving that certain Cayley graphs are expander.

Let $S$ be the multiplicative semigroup of matrices generated by $A = \left(
 \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ and $C = \left(
 \begin{array}{cc} c  & d \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $a,c\geq 2$, $A$ and $C$ don't commute, and $p$ is an odd prime.

Considering the Cayley graph $\Gamma_p(S, \{A,C\})$, is there a result that implies that $\Gamma_p$ is family of expander graphs? Any suggestions on how to prove it or disprove it?

Thanks in advance!

PS.: The semigroup generated by $A$ and $B$ is a free semigroup over $\mathbb{Z}$. So no product can ever be expressed more simply in terms of other elements, that is , there are no relations in the semgroup.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$. I'll edit the question to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But then, the semigroup generated by $A$ and $C$ is finite and cannot be free...

Comment: Yes, again I need to edit. The semigroup generated by $A$ and $C$ if free over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Again, since the semigroup generated by $A$ and $C$ is finite, there are nontrivial relations in the semigroup. For instance, every matrix $M$ has an idempotent power, which gives a relation of the form $M^n = M^{2n}$.

Comment: The freeness of the these semigroups is over $\mathbb{Z}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. The only reason why I mentioned is because while reading about expanders (for groups) I realized that it may be (or not) useful fact.